# How can I get the commit diff in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab CI for checking a code quality of my project. Sometime I want to check only new code ( new commit ).
How can I get diff from Gitlab CI ?

Comment: A diff from what to what, exactly? A CI pipeline need not be for a Merge Request.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It would be just commit from local:master to origin:master, I want get diff from last commit and previous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out solution, it was obvious, but not for me

```
 diff:
   script:
     - git diff ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} master
   except:
     - master
```

Comment: Can we replace master by the branch for which the MR is created?

Comment: You can. Set "only: - merge_requests" setting for the job. Variables can be found here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html .They start with prefix CI_MERGE_REQUEST.